# How to add jenkins cred id to build.gradle?

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I can't figure out how I can tell gradle to take the credentials id from jenkins and apply them? I use such a construct in build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name ’test'
        url «test.com"
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_ID")
            password = System.getenv("JENKINS_CREDENTIALS_ID")
        }
    }
}
```

How do I transfer the account id from jenkins?

Comment: Are you trying to access the credentials from the Jenkins Credentials store?

Comment: No, from build.gradle of my service. 
gradle.build -> jenkins credentials store

Comment: Have you already read through this page and found none of them is working for you? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials